# JPA executing before insert trigger in one project and having different behavior on another

Tags: java, oracle, jsf, jpa, triggers

Yeah, I know, title is kinda confusing, but here is the situation:

I have two projects, that should work the same way. Both of them access a Oracle database. Each table on Oracle database have an TABLENAME_ID column that is the primary key, which is associated with a BEFORE INSERT trigger that does a TABLENAME_SEQ nextval() to insert into the TABLENAME_ID column. (Got that?). On this environment, inserting through SQL works fine.

That said let's go to the issue:

I have a Project1 that uses JPA where entities were generated from Database Tables. Entities generated on this project work fine and does CRUD and search perfectly. Entities are associated to a SequenceGenerator annotation the DOESN'T executes database trigger on insert, so id rows are generated sequentially no matter what channel is used (system or SQL DML statements).

Now I have to create a second project that should behave the same way but is not. On this project when I create an entity it retrieves me i. e. ID = 3, but actually writes ID = 4 on database. So, if I get this same entity and try to do an update on that, JPA tries to INSERT it again, and gives me an error.

Any clues? Some code follows bellow:

Entity example (FROM PROJECT 1):

```
@Entity
public class Category implements Serializable {

    private static final long               serialVersionUID    = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CATEGORY_CATEGORYID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "CATEGORY_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CATEGORY_CATEGORYID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10)
    private long                            categoryId;

    @Column(name = "IS_ACTIVE", nullable = false, precision = 3)
    private boolean                         isActive;

    @Column(name = "LONG_TITLE", nullable = false, length = 250)
    private String                          longTitle;

    public Category() {
    }

    public long getCategoryId() {
        return this.categoryId;
    }

    public boolean getIsActive() {
        return this.isActive;
    }

    public String getLongTitle() {
        return this.longTitle;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(long categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public void setIsActive(boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    public void setLongTitle(String longTitle) {
        this.longTitle = longTitle;
    }

}
```

Entity example (FROM PROJECT 2):

```
@Entity
public class Author implements Serializable {

    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "AUTHOR_AUTHORID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "AUTHOR_AUTHOR_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "AUTHOR_AUTHORID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name = "AUTHOR_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10)
    private long                authorId;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_COMPLEMENT")
    private String              addressComplement;

    @Column(name = "AUTHOR_KIND")
    private int                 authorKind;

    @Column(name = "BUILDING_NUMBER")
    private String              buildingNumber;

    private String              city;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Product
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    private List<Product>       products;

    public Author() {
    }

    public String getAddressComplement() {
        return addressComplement;
    }

    public long getAuthorId() {
        return authorId;
    }

    public int getAuthorKind() {
        return authorKind;
    }

    public String getBuildingNumber() {
        return buildingNumber;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setAddressComplement(String addressComplement) {
        this.addressComplement = addressComplement;
    }

    public void setAuthorId(long authorId) {
        this.authorId = authorId;
    }

    public void setAuthorKind(int authorKind) {
        this.authorKind = authorKind;
    }

    public void setBuildingNumber(String buildingNumber) {
        this.buildingNumber = buildingNumber;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

aS  JScoobyCed asked, here follows how second entity code is used:

```
// ...
Author author = new Author();
// Here follows setters
// Code below returns, ie, author_id = 3, but saves author_id = 4 on database
author = authotEjb.create(author);
// ...
product.setAuthor(author);
// Don't find author_id = 3 on database and tries to insert author again
// or complains about PERSIST cascade on Product entitiy.
product = productEjb.update(product)
```

EJB is using EntityManager.persist() on create() method and EntityManager.merge() on update method.

**EDIT 2**

Adding sequence and trigger codes. Each table has it's own sequence and it's own trigger the follow the same pattern TABLENAME_SEQ and TABLENAME_TRG:

Sequence code:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  AUTHOR_SEQ  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE  ORDER  NOCYCLE;
```

Trigger code:

```
create or replace 
trigger author_trg before insert on author
for each row 
begin 
    select author_seq.nextval into :new.author_id from dual; 
end;
```

Comment: Can you post code about how you are using these entities, in particular for your 2nd project. Maybe your entity is not (no more)  managed by JPA at the time you want to update it.

Comment: Are triggers on both tables same? Is trigger on Category checking if id is already set before setting it?

Comment: Each table has it's own sequence and it's own trigger to "before insert" event, there is no verify of id existence. I'll add trigger and sequence code...

Comment: Try removing the create author line. Jpa should be able to create it when you update product

Comment: I've tried this approach already, problem is that when updating object it inserts into database but this action do not retrieve object's id to memory.

`product = productEjb.update(product)`
`// product.getProductId() = 0`
`// product.getAuthor().getAuthorId() = 0`

If I try to do another update on the same object later (which I need to do), JPA will try to insert it again.

Answer (score 0):

Both your trigger and JPA will try to allocate the sequence id, so this should not work on either system.

You need to fix your trigger to not allocate an id if the insert provide the id (only do it if null).

Otherwise, you need some way of getting the id back form the trigger for JPA.  If using EclipseLink, you could use the @ReturnInsert annotation, but in general fixing the trigger would be much better.

Comment: The strange is that, as said before, I have two projects where this scenario (a trigger that calls the sequence before insert) works on Project 1, but doesn't work on Project 2.

Answer (score 0):

We decided to disable the triggers on database...

We suspect Project 1 works on similar scenario because o remote EJBs, but we are not entirely sure. Thanks to all who tried to help me on this issue.